# Storyboard.TargetProperty path contains nonanimatable property 'Text

Tags: c#, eventtrigger

Edit:

I'am trying to change Text of TextBox with event trigger, But I am getting a run time error like below.

System.InvalidOperationException: ''(0)' Storyboard.TargetProperty path contains nonanimatable property 'Text'.'

How to change Text with event trigger in WPF

```
<Style x:Key="mystyle"
           TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">

                    <StackPanel>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                                      Focusable="false"
                                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />

                        <ToggleButton HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                Content="search"
                                Name="searchButton">
                            <ToggleButton.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.Target="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBox,AncestorLevel=1}}"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBox.Text)">
                                                <DiscreteStringKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00"
                                                                        Value="texttwo" />
                                            </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </ToggleButton.Triggers>
                        </ToggleButton>
                    </StackPanel>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit: since you have totally rewritten the original question, my original answer does not make sense anymore, so I will rewrite it as well.

The problem is that in the EventTrigger you can only use a StoryBoard, and you cannot set the Text property of the TextBox from it. Therefore I think even if it can be achieved purely from WPF with a Template, the solution would be so complicated and ugly that it does not worth it, so I would suggest to create a user control.
If we make a step backward, what is your goal with this customized TextBox?

Edit2:
Finally I could do it with a custom animation class, but I still think that implementing this functionality with a user control is the good solution.
This is the custom animation class (for sake of simplicity I have put it in "local" namespace):

```
    public class TextBoxStringAnimation : StringAnimationBase {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBoxToChangeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(TextBoxToChange), typeof(TextBox), typeof(TextBoxStringAnimation));
        public TextBox TextBoxToChange {
            get => (TextBox)this.GetValue(TextBoxToChangeProperty);
            set => this.SetValue(TextBoxToChangeProperty, value);
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty NewTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(NewText), typeof(string), typeof(TextBoxStringAnimation));
        public string NewText {
            get => (string)this.GetValue(NewTextProperty);
            set => this.SetValue(NewTextProperty, value);
        }
        protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore() => new TextBoxStringAnimation();
        protected override string GetCurrentValueCore(string defaultOriginValue, string defaultDestinationValue, AnimationClock animationClock) {
            TextBoxToChange.Text = NewText;
            return defaultDestinationValue;
        }
        protected override bool FreezeCore(bool isChecking) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

This inherits from StringAnimationBase, and you can set the TextBox and the NewText values directly. I have implemented both as dependency properties, so you can bind them.

When getting the current value (GetCurrentValueCore) it simply sets the Text property of the target TextBox. I had to override FreezeCore, because by default it has returned false, and that causes an InvelidOperationException when the animation is triggered.

So this is an animation that does not animate at all. :) I consider this an ugly solution, but without using a user control I could not come up with a better solution.

Below is the XAML markup. You must set the TargetProperty of the animation, although at the end it is not used - that is why I have specified Tag. If you use the Tag property of the textbox, check if the animation resets it or not.

```
        <Style x:Key="mystyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />

                            <ToggleButton HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="search" Name="searchButton">
                                <ToggleButton.Triggers>
                                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <local:TextBoxStringAnimation TextBoxToChange="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBox,AncestorLevel=1}}"
                                                                              NewText="texttwo" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBox.Tag)"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </EventTrigger>
                                </ToggleButton.Triggers>
                            </ToggleButton>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Hi @household UFO. I noticed the problem the first time I asked the question.Sorry for completely changing the question. My goal is to assign a default value to textbox when the button is clicked. I didn't want to create a new user control.I thought I could solve this problem by giving style.

Comment: No problem, I just wanted to keep things consistent. :) Maybe it could be solved with a custom animation. I have an idea, but I can only try it out on Monday.